# Any packages or library for HQ/Comic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

is there a package or library that makes it easy to create and edit comic book diagrams (HQ or comic) using tex, tikz, pgf, pstricks, etc.?

Comment: The `tikzlings` package.

Comment: @abcdefg ThankXD. You meant that it comes with ready characters, but I mean about setting up dialogue balloons and scene frames.

Comment: Callouts can be created with the `shapes.callouts` library of Ti*k*Z. However, I am not aware of any large collection of scenes (unless a "scene frame" just refers to a frame, which can be drawn easily).

Comment: @abcdefg  I can make all the scene frames using shapes.callouts but I wanted to automate. But given your answer, I imagine that there is no library or package ready to automate this work. I'll finish this post. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the fact that one user is not aware of such tools certainly does not imply that they do not exist. Maybe someone else has more information.